# Integration of Google Calendar into MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-calendar-api

I don't normally ask for help on stack overflow, but when I do, it's usually after pulling out my hair for at least a few days!

That said, I'm having a heck of a time integrating Google Calendar in my MVC app. I need to be able to ask my users for their authorization and then do stuff with their calendar such as create events. I wouldn't say I'm having trouble getting the authorization from the user necessarily, but rather once I have it, how to go about using the refresh token. Or maybe I'm just not understanding the work flow.

Anyhow, Google's documentation on this is dismal at best. Searching for answers has been fruitless. The best solution I was able to find and actually make work is from here: [nanovazquez/google-calendar-sample](https://github.com/nanovazquez/google-calendar-sample). Unfortunately that example is using a really early build and a lot had changed since.

So my question is this: does anyone know of, or have any working examples of an MVC project that uses the latest (or a more recent version) of the Google Calendar v3 api?

THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there's not going to be a lot of help in this area. I finally managed to figure things out for myself from what ever materials I was able to find. I suggest to start by creating a mock-up project to test things out. Once you have that working, you can port what you have over to an existing project. Be advised though, if it doesn't work there you'll probably end up doing a bit of sleuthing to chase down the problem that's not necessarily related to Google's API.